# XSLT: how to propagate previous value until a new one is found

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm looking for 1.0 XSLT transformation that would propagate non empty cells until a new one is found.
My input:

```
<table>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value1</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
</table>
```

Expected output:

```
<table>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value1</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value1</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value1</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
</table>
```

I have tried to use preceding::row[1]/column_1 but ended up with only one copy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="replace-value">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//column_1">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".=''">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace-value">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="preceding::row[1]/column_1/text()"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

like:

```
<table>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value1</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value1</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1>Value2</column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
<row>
    <column_1></column_1>
    <column_2></column_2>
</row>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, but instead of this:

```
preceding::row[1]/column_1/text()
```

you needed this:

```
preceding::row[column_1 != ''][1]/column_1/text()
```

and that can be further simplified to this:

```
preceding::column_1[. != ''][1]
```

since you need to find the last row with a non-blank column.

On the other hand, I can't see any reason to use that replace-value template.  Your XSLT could be simplified to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="column_1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=".=''">
          <xsl:value-of select="preceding::column_1[. != ''][1]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

yYou could try within your otherwise clause save the value you want to propagate downwards in an <xsl:variable name="saved" select=".">, and then in the line:

<xsl:with-param name="value" select="preceding::row[1]/column_1/text()"/>

do instead

<xsl:with-param name="value" select="$saved"/>

Depending on how many different columns you may want to use unique variable names.